# Error installing AMDGPU Drivers on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, dpkg, amdgpu

Here's the complete log of the installation:

```
$ sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation --vulkan=pro
Hit:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease                                          
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu lunar InRelease                         
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                             
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease                                             
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                
Hit:8 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.5.3/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.5.3 jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
amdgpu-pro is already the newest version (23.10-1620044.22.04).
amdgpu-pro-lib32 is already the newest version (23.10-1620044.22.04).
amdgpu-dkms is already the newest version (1:6.0.5.50503-1620033.22.04).
vulkan-amdgpu-pro is already the newest version (23.10-1620044.22.04).
vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 is already the newest version (23.10-1620044.22.04).
linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic is already the newest version (6.2.0-27.28).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 179 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:6.0.5.50503-1620033.22.04) ...
Removing old amdgpu-6.0.5-1620033.22.04 DKMS files...
Deleting module amdgpu-6.0.5-1620033.22.04 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new amdgpu-6.0.5-1620033.22.04 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-27-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.2.0-27-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms; however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                       dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu; however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu; however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 23.10-1620044.22.04); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also `uname -a`

```
Linux roxxel-MS-7A36 6.2.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jul 12 22:39:51 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm not sure if any additional info is needed

EDIT: I'm installing latest drivers downloaded from AMD website
`Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 23.10.3 for Ubuntu 22.04.2`
`Revision Number: 23.10.3`

Comment: Why aren't you using the drivers offered by Ubuntu? Usually they have to be compiled against your current kernel version. Check for an "Additional driver" app